# Set pixels are changed after drawing an image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-conversion

In my project get each and every pixel value of image then perform decryption on pixel and set new value to the pixel. But after create new image with changed pixel values, the new image can't contain same pixel values what i change as it is. Major pixel values are change. How to solve this problem.
My code is

```
     for( i=0;i<width;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++){

            //int p1 = pix[i][j];
            int a1 = ealph[i][j];           
            int r3 = ered[i][j];
            int g1 = ered[i][j];
            int b1 = ered[i][j];


            int p1 = (a1<<24) | (r3<<16) | (g1<<8) | b1;
                img.setRGB(i, j, p1);

        }

    }

    try{
        f = new File("C:\\Users\\chukkapalli\\workspace\\Des_Encryption\\decripted_img.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
      }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
      }


  f = null;

 img = null;
    try{
          f = new File("C:\\Users\\chukkapalli\\workspace\\Des_Encryption\\decripted_img.jpg");
          img = ImageIO.read(f);
        }catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }
     width = img.getWidth();
     height = img.getHeight();

     for( i=0;i<width;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){

                int p1 = img.getRGB(i,j);
                e1alph[i][j] = (p1>>24)&0xff;
                e1red[i][j] = (p1>>16)&0xff;
                egreen[i][j] = (p1>>8)&0xff;
                eblue[i][j] = p1&0xff;

                System.out.println("orginal image- "+ealph[i][j]+" "+ered[i][j]+" "+ered[i][j]+" "+ered[i][j]+" created -- "+e1alph[i][j]+" "+e1red[i][j]+" "+egreen[i][j]+" "+eblue[i][j]);

            }

        }
```

Output is

```
     orginal image- 0 33 33 33 created -- 255 35 35 35
     orginal image- 0 38 38 38 created -- 255 41 41 41
     orginal image- 0 140 140 140 created -- 255 142 142 142
     orginal image- 0 81 81 81 created -- 255 51 51 51
     orginal image- 0 22 22 22 created -- 255 21 21 21
     orginal image- 0 127 127 127 created -- 255 135 135 135
     orginal image- 0 126 126 126 created -- 255 127 127 127
     orginal image- 0 63 63 63 created -- 255 62 62 62
     orginal image- 0 244 244 244 created -- 255 250 250 250
     orginal image- 0 11 11 11 created -- 255 0 0 0
     orginal image- 0 13 13 13 created -- 255 11 11 11
     orginal image- 0 171 171 171 created -- 255 175 175 175
     orginal image- 0 126 126 126 created -- 255 130 130 130
     orginal image- 0 8 8 8 created -- 255 0 0 0
     orginal image- 0 6 6 6 created -- 255 14 14 14
     orginal image- 0 248 248 248 created -- 255 244 244 244
     orginal image- 0 109 109 109 created -- 255 128 128 128
     orginal image- 0 107 107 107 created -- 255 86 86 86
     orginal image- 0 50 50 50 created -- 255 48 48 48
     orginal image- 0 104 104 104 created -- 255 131 131 131
     orginal image- 0 110 110 110 created -- 255 95 95 95
     orginal image- 0 127 127 127 created -- 255 128 128 128
```

How can i create image with out change pixel value after created.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a lossless format like PNG. JPG changes pixel values in its compresssion and cannot be read exactly like it was created.